# Retrofit returns 500 Internal server error

Tags: android, json, api, retrofit, retrofit2

I am trying to update databse record using Retrofit library. The postman works fine with same data. GET data is also working fine but PATCH operation is returning Error 500 Internal server error.

Interface:

```
   //@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @PATCH("usersapi/{id}")
    Call<UserBank> updateUserBank(@Path("id") int id, @Body UserBank post);
```

Main activity:

```
  retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://<website>/api/")
               // .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

       

        jsonCofyBizApi = retrofit.create(jsonCofyBizApi.class);

        UserBank post = new UserBank(user_id, txtbankname.getText().toString());
            
            Call<UserBank> call = jsonCofyBizApi.updateUserBank(user_id, post);

            call.enqueue(new Callback<UserBank>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<UserBank> call, Response<UserBank> response) {
                    UserBank postResponse = response.body();
```

and rest of the code...

Class/ Constructor UserBank:

```
public class UserBank {
    @SerializedName("user_id")
    int user_id;
    @SerializedName("bank_name")
    String bank_name;
  

    public UserBank(int user_id, String bank_name)
    {
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.bank_name = bank_name;
     }
```

rest of the code...

I saw other threads with the same topic but none of the solution is working for me. The url is getting properly generated.

Any help appreciated.
Regards,
PD

Comment: what do you expect as an answer here? how do we know that there isn't a problem on the server ? how do you expect us to recreate this problem on our side ?

Comment: add your API response in question.

Comment: As specified GET is already working and through Postman also its working

Comment: We have no idea what code your server is running that's throwing this error, or what you did differently in Postman.

Comment: I undestand. It's difficult to reproduce at your end. I would appreciate if somone can tell ways to get more info from retrofit about the return. I would try to implement to get more log.

Comment: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=500, message=Internal Server Error, url=https://<sitename>/api/usersapi/1}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. Added '/' at the end of the specified endpoint

```
 @PATCH("usersapi/{id}")
    Call<UserBank> updateUserBank(@Path("id") int id, @Body UserBank post);

 @PATCH("usersapi/{id}/")
    Call<UserBank> updateUserBank(@Path("id") int id, @Body UserBank post);
```